# UIPageViewController with Scroll Transition Style automatically adds Safe Area insets for iPhone X

Tags: uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I'm developing image gallery like slider using `UIPageViewController` and I'm having troubles with `UIPageViewController` automatic insets in `Scroll` transition style mode.

Here is my layout:

1. `UIViewController` with `UIContainerView` (magenta background)
2. `UIPageViewController` linked to the container (from #1)
3. List of dynamically created view `UIViewController(s)` within the page controller (from #2), full width-height views (1. orange, 2. red, 3. green)

[image]

It used to work fine for a long time and continue to work with iOS 11 unless it's rendered on iPhone X device with safe area:

[image]

I've checked a lot of various options and was able to confirm that it's related specifically to the Scroll mode of the Page Controller. If I switch to PageCurl transition style - it works as expected (full height):

[image]

The Page Controller doesn't expose a lot of options to control this behavior for the scroll mode and I wasn't able to "hack" it as well by searching the controls tree and modifying various `insets` and `frame` and `contentSize` related properties. What I can clearly see is that once view controller is created, my scroll view `contentSize` and `frame` is `34px` smaller then the container `frame`

```
> view.frame
{{X=0,Y=0,Width=375,Height=732}}
    Bottom: 732
    Height: 732
    IsEmpty: false
    Left: 0
    Location: {{X=0, Y=0}}
    Right: 375
    Size: {{Width=375, Height=732}}
    Top: 0
    Width: 375
    X: 0
    Y: 0

> scroll.frame
{{X=-5,Y=0,Width=385,Height=698}}
    Bottom: 698
    Height: 698
    IsEmpty: false
    Left: -5
    Location: {{X=-5, Y=0}}
    Right: 380
    Size: {{Width=385, Height=698}}
    Top: 0
    Width: 385
    X: -5
    Y: 0

> scroll.contentSize
{{Width=1155, Height=698}}
    Height: 698
    IsEmpty: false
    Width: 1155
```

I've also set up my autolayout constraints to be linked to superview rather than safe area:

[image]

Here is my code for the Home Controller and all the rest is set in a storyboard (alert: C# Xamarin syntax)

```
private List<UIViewController> viewControllers;

public HomePageViewController (IntPtr handle) : base ( handle)
{
}

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    var child1 = new UIViewController();
    child1.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
    var child2 = new UIViewController();
    child2.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    var child3 = new UIViewController();
    child3.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

    this.viewControllers = new List<UIViewController>
    {
        child1,
        child2,
        child3,
    };

    this.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { child1 }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, false, null);

    this.GetNextViewController = (c, r) =>
    {
        var current = this.viewControllers.IndexOf(this.ViewControllers[0]);
        if (current >= this.viewControllers.Count - 1)
            return null;

        return this.viewControllers[current + 1];
    };

    this.GetPreviousViewController = (c, r) =>
    {
        var current = this.viewControllers.IndexOf(this.ViewControllers[0]);
        if (current <= 0)
            return null;

        return this.viewControllers[current - 1];
    };
}
```

How can I force my children view controllers to have full height (equals to the frame height of the parent container)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this issue using code and custom layout. I mean create your `UIPageViewController` and insert its view to your UIViewController *in code* **not on storyboard**. I think you
should override `UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and set your rects "manually" (at least the one of the UIPageViewController.) *Well, when you do it in code, sometimes you even don't need to override `UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` because the template by Apple itself didn't do this. I think because any created view has `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` **= true**. So you can also follow this approach.*

There is an example when you create a new project and state it is a `page based app`.

Here is the template if you want (WARNING: This is a part of a template by Apple itself)

```
    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.
    self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    self.pageViewController!.delegate = self

    let startingViewController: DataViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
    let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
    self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: {done in })

    self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)

    // Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
    var pageViewRect = self.view.bounds
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        pageViewRect = pageViewRect.insetBy(dx: 40.0, dy: 40.0)
    }
    self.pageViewController!.view.frame = pageViewRect

    self.pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

You can extend this functionality by extending

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that only happened in the X sizes and after hours of trails and errors I got it fixed.

I am not sure if it's applicable for you or not but the way I have my page view controller VCs is that each VC has an image filling its background. I have 3 pages. Scrolling for the first time looked normal but when I would reverse scroll from page 2 to 1 or from 1 to 0, page 1's image would show around 40 pixels from the side when it should be completely hidden (similar to your screenshots).

So to fix it I had to either set the images to Aspect Fit or `clips to bounds = true`. I used the latter because it worked better for the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to have my `UIPageViewController` display with full screen height with the following code :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    guard let contentScrollView = view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) else { return }
    contentScrollView.frame.size.height = view.frame.height
}
```